# jQuery div/box reposition (similar to hubpages capsules)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for some help setting up a page with re-positional divs/boxes.

I would like the functionality similar to how you can setup capsules with HubPages, which includes moving boxes:

1. Up
2. Down
3. Float right (making 2 columns)
4. Change to full width (if floated right)
5. Remove box
6. Insert new boxes

See screenshot for example:

[image: http://imgur.com/n4YRC.png]

I don't want to use drag-n-drop jQuery UI, but rather have buttons to reposition the boxes.

Example video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=7SnOtOwTYoE#t=74s

Comment: you say you don't want jquery drag and drop ui, but yet you want to drag and drop (from what I understood) and you tagged your question jQuery and jquery-ui. Or wait was don't a typo? or am I not undestanding your question correctly?

Comment: Yeah, maybe i'm not describing it the best. If you've ever setup a Hub with HubPages, you'll know what I mean. It can use jQuery UI if it works how I need it to. It's not drag-n-drop exactly, but buttons that rearrange the boxes: http://imgur.com/n4YRC.png

Comment: So you want a predefined 'grid' where you could use buttons to move an element from one cell to another. For instance you click the 'right' button and the element jumps to the button of the right column. Is that right?

Comment: Pretty much, but with options to have cells/divs move: up, down, float right (floats right of the box below it), full width (spans all columns).

Comment: You can see it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=7SnOtOwTYoE#t=74s

Answer (score 1):

You could do a somewhat low-level DOM manipulation using only jQuery. For example, moving a box up:

```
$('a.move-up').click(function(){
  var prev = $(this).parent().prev();       // get the preceding element
  var self = $(this).parent().clone(true);  // copy the parent element, including all event handlers attached to itself and its children
  $(this).parent().remove();                // remove the parent
  prev.before(self);                        // place the parent before the preceding element to "move it up"
});
```

The code above assumes the markup below, but can easily be adapted to any other markup you may have (`$(this).parents('div')`, e.g.)

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="" class="move-up"></a></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

This is just a very crude example of how you could achieve such a result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this links might help you out:

[jQuery Sortable Move UP/DOWN Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951941/jquery-sortable-move-up-down-button)

[Sortable using a up/down link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-using-a-up-down-link)