# How to move Listbox items up and down

Tags: c#, asp.net, listboxitem

I have a listBox1 and it contains some items. I have a button to move selected item up and another to move selected item down. What should the code be to the two buttons?

This is a web application

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Sortable Move UP/DOWN Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951941/jquery-sortable-move-up-down-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a similar solution using jQuery

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2951988/1005142